# How to remove Unused Vertex Groups but not Parent that have The Used Vertex Groups or Children that have Used Vertex Groups?

Tags: scripting

How to remove Unused Vertex Groups but not Parent that have The Used Vertex Groups or Children that have Used Vertex Groups?

I need fast way
but I didn't find script about that